# Overlapping dates in PowerQuery

Tags: date, max, powerquery, min, overlap

So I have a table with StartDate and EndDate and I need to know if this dates overlap in a natural year. In example January 1st 2021 and December 31st 2021 and know how many days where in that period.

I have a formula that works in PowerBI that is:

*Note: "DATA" is the name of the query.*

**OVERLAP days 2021 = MAX(MIN(DATE(2021,12,31),'DATA'[StartDate].[Date])-MAX(DATE(2021,1,1),'DATA'[EndDate].[Date])+1,0)**

But now I need to translate it to PowerQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
let Source = #table({"StartDate", "EndDate"},{{#date(2021,5,31),#date(2021,7,31)}}),
year=2021,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Overlap", each 
    if [EndDate]<#date(year,1,1) or [StartDate]>#date(year,12,31) or [EndDate]<[StartDate] then null else 
    Number.From(if [EndDate]<#date(year,1,1) then #date(year,1,1) 
    else if [EndDate]>#date(year,12,31) then #date(year,12,31) 
    else [EndDate]) -
    Number.From(if [StartDate]<#date(year,1,1) then #date(year,1,1) 
    else if [StartDate]>#date(year,12,31) then #date(year,12,31)
    else [StartDate]))
in #"Added Custom"
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithm is pretty much the same.  But I confess I got a bit carried away with implementing it.

The problem is in how you want to define the years of interest, and how you want to display the result when there are multiple years.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

Here is a method using various M-Coding to develop

- a list of all the years that are represented in the table
- `List.Generate` to generate a list of days in any one Year
- `List.Accumulate` to iterate through List.Generate for each year
- Some other functions to create the table with the additional columns.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Start Date", type date}, {"End Date", type date}}),

//add columns for each year
  //create list of years for the table
    Years = 
        let 
            firstYear = List.Transform(#"Changed Type"[Start Date], each Date.Year(_)),
            lastYear = List.Transform(#"Changed Type"[End Date], each Date.Year(_))
        in 
            List.Numbers(List.Min(firstYear), List.Max(lastYear) - List.Min(firstYear)+1),

//create lists of days count for each year, based on the start and end dates
newcols = List.Accumulate(Years, {}, (state, current) => state & 
    {let 
        ends = List.Transform(#"Changed Type"[End Date], each List.Min({#date(current,12,31), _})),
        starts = List.Transform(#"Changed Type"[Start Date], each List.Max({#date(current-1,12,31), _})),
        dys = List.Generate(
            ()=>[d=List.Max({0,Duration.Days(ends{0} - starts {0})}), idx=0],
            each [idx] < List.Count(ends),
            each [d=List.Max({0,Duration.Days(ends{[idx]+1} - starts {[idx]+1})}), idx=[idx]+1],
            each [d]
            )
    in 
        dys}),

//add the new columns to original table
    newColNames = List.Transform(Years, each "Days in " & Text.From(_)),
    newTable = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") & newcols,
        Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type") & newColNames),
//Set data types
    typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(newTable, List.Transform(newColNames, each {_, Int64.Type}))
    
in
  typed
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidCisneros Sorry. I thought you were more familiar.  I've pasted some instructions into my answer.  If you still get an error, be sure to include the error text, and also the **earliest** `Applied Step` at which it appears.

Comment: I'm just stuck in the last part of **//Set data types** if I add the chunk of code it gives me an error on the *"in typed"* part. Am I missing to do something? thanks! Note I had to add brackets in the names on the columns so the formula actually works.

If I remove the "*in typed"* at the end it says no error in Syntax, but it gives me an error in the table. Saying "Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator - to types Date and DateTime."

Comment: @DavidCisneros Those errors lead me to believe you have done something wrong in adapting the code to your situation.  Try following the instructions precisely, changing ONLY the data source line to point to the correct table. And have the column names in the original table exactly as shown -- no brackets, case sensitive.

Comment: @DavidCisneros Consider uploading a file (with sensitive data removed) that demonstrates your errors to some sharing site (eg OneDrive, DropBox) and posting a link here.

Comment: Hey so I added your code to the Excel and it works. 

I did the same now with the Power BI file that I need it to do it for, but when I do it it creates an Error to the other columns. Not sure why, but it says Error in yellow it seems that it changes something to other columns on the last step **typed**. Also before processing, the algorithm it takes about 30 minutes to run it. This must be because of the huge data. Any advise? thanks!

Comment: I found the answer, I had to add at the last part that it doesn't convert other columns(**each _ <> "End Date" and _ <> "Start Date"**), can I do a reference that it only converts the new columns and not the previous ones?

Comment: @DavidCisneros Code edited so that it only sets the data type on the columns we just added.